# ReactJS - axios interceptor onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, interceptor

Structure:

```
ApiService.js
components/
          TrackComponent.jsx
```

> TrackComponent.jsx

I have this form in my React in `render()` that triggers an event that hits one endpoint:

```
<form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleEditPlaylist(event) }>
 <div className="field">
   <input
     name="artist"
     className="input is-dark is-large"
     type="text"
   />
  </div>
</form>
```

handle function:

```
handleEditPlaylist(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formType = this.props.formType
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    const {userId} = this.props
    const data = {
      value: this.state.formData.value,
      spotify_token: this.props.spotifyToken
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/handle_edit_playlist/${this.state.artist}/${userId}`;

    axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
        if(data){this.clearForm();}
      })
      .catch((err) => {
    });

    axios.get(url, { 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
      }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          this.setState({
            seeds: res.data.data[0].seeds,
            artist: res.data.data[0].artist,
          })
      })
  };
```

This works.

---

> Api instance inside component

Now, I have this `axios` interceptor that must me instantiated in my component above, in order to handle access tokens, which have two endpoints.

```
import Axios from 'axios';

class ApiService {
  constructor() {
    this.axios = Axios.create();
    this.axios.interceptors.response.use(null, this.authInterceptor.bind(this));

    this.get = this.axios.get.bind(this.axios);
    this.post = this.axios.post.bind(this.axios);
  }

  async authorize() {
    console.log('Async in authorize')
    const { accessToken } = await this.axios.post('/get_token/1', {});
    this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    return accessToken; // return it to the component that invoked it to store in some state
  }

  async getTrack(userId, spotifyToken, artist) { // <---------------------------
    console.log('getAroma in ApiService', userId, spotifyToken, artist)
    return this.axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get-tracks/${artist}/${userId}/${spotifyToken}`
    );
  }

  async updateAccessToken(userId) {
    const { accessToken } = await this.axios.post(`/refresh-token/1`, {});
    this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
  }

  (...)

export const apiService = new ApiService(); // this is a single instance of the service, each import of this file will get it
```

---

I would like to have the same `onSubmit` event above trigger the interceptor instantiation call as well. On its own, I could do like so:

```
import {apiService} from '../ApiService';

async getTrack(event) {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      const {userId, spotifyToken} = this.props;
      const {artist} = this.state.artist
      const aromaticTracks = await apiService.getTracks(userId, spotifyToken, artist);
      this.setState({newTracks});
    } else {
      this.setState({newTracks: []});
    }
  }
```

---

If I insert this async getTrack in `handleEditPlaylist`, right after form is submitted, like so:

```
(...)

axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        this.getTrack(); // <----------- HERE
        console.log(data);
        if(data){this.clearForm();}
      })
(...)
```

**I get 'undefined' for form submitted values (artist) in `async getTrack`     `console.log('getTrack in ApiService', userId, spotifyToken, artist)`, but print the value submitted in `console.log(data)` right bellow..**

---

How do I properly handle this interceptor `onSubmit`?

Comment: what issue do you face. Do you receive any error

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri pease refer to my edit. sorry if the question was not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue in your code is because you are trying to destructure a value from state which you are already accessing

```
async getTrack(event) {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      const {userId, spotifyToken} = this.props;
      const {artist} = this.state; // this needs to be this.state and not this.state.artist
      const aromaticTracks = await apiService.getTracks(userId, spotifyToken, artist);
      this.setState({newTracks});
    } else {
      this.setState({newTracks: []});
    }
  }
```

The `destructuring` assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Read the documentation for [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: thanks a lot. could you please briefly explain what 'destructure a value' means in your answer?